# How to stop resizing popup window totally below certain size

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lock resizing of popup window? not even drag should be possible

```
newWidth < 650 ? window.innerWidth = 650 : $(window).height();
newHeight < 400 ? window.innerHeight = 400 : $(window).width()

/* OR  $(function() {
                $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
                maxHeight: 450,
                maxWidth: 650,
                minHeight: 150,
                minWidth: 200
                });
                }); */
```

in both dragging is possible...

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable dragging on a window that you opened via `window.open`?

Comment: you will never be able to reliably manipulated drag behaviour cross browser (i dont even know if its possible in any browser). maybe creating a overlaying fixed position div box is a better solution to your problem. (popups are very annoying to the user and will force new tabs on mobile devices, always a bad solution imo)

Comment: You may want to try using a modal instead of a popup window. You won't be able to restrict dragging a popup window.

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery Modal Dialog box.

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false, //draggable false
    resizable: false, //resizable false
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

check out this example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/)